# In PDFMake I set the height and width of table, but it isn't work

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I've created tables with pdfmake. The pagesize and the columns size was fixed. But the two table in one row is merging. What should I do?

An another problem is that in the second column isn't showing.

The document definition is

```js
{
  pageSize: { width: 595.275590551181, height: 841.8897637795275 },
  pageMargins: [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  content: [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          width: 297.6377952755905,
          table: {
            headerRows: 2,
            widths: [ 148.81889763779526, 148.81889763779526 ],
            heights: [
              59.932508436445445,
              59.932508436445445,
              59.932508436445445,
              59.932508436445445,
              59.932508436445445,
              59.932508436445445,
              59.932508436445445
            ],
            body: [
              [ { text: '108', colSpan: 2 } ],
              [
                { text: 'Név', colspan: 1 },
                { text: 'Csoport', colspan: 1 }
              ],
              [ { text: 'I', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ],
              [ { text: 'Y', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ],
              [ { text: 'Z', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ],
              [ { text: 'K', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ],
              [ { text: 'X', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          width: 297.6377952755905,
          table: {
            headerRows: 2,
            widths: [ 148.81889763779526, 148.81889763779526 ],
            heights: [
              83.90551181102362,
              83.90551181102362,
              83.90551181102362,
              83.90551181102362,
              83.90551181102362
            ],
            body: [
              [ { text: '206', colSpan: 2 } ],
              [
                { text: 'Név', colspan: 1 },
                { text: 'Csoport', colspan: 1 }
              ],
              [ { text: 'U', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ],
              [ { text: 'Q', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ],
              [ { text: 'I', colspan: 1 }, { text: '-', colspan: 1 } ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      columnGap: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by setting margin in each table:

```
                   //Here change the margin values according to your requirement
                   margin: [20, 5, 0, 10],
```